# Write string to a file without a shell

Tags: files, scripting, command, output

Suppose I have an environment where there isn't a shell running, so I can't use redirection, pipes, here-documents or other shell-isms, but I *can* launch a command (through [`execvp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) or some similar way).  I want to write an arbitrary string to a named file.  Is there a standard command that will do something like:

```
somecommand  outputfile 'string'
```

for instance:

```
somecommand /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward '1'
```

A really dumb example might be:

```
curl -o /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward http://example.com/1.txt
```

where I set up 1.txt to contain the string I want.

Is there a common command that can be abused to do this?

Comment: This would never fly, total vector for hacker to exploit.

Comment: Why is writing to a file a vector for hackers?  The file is written with the standard privileges of the calling user (so the /proc/sys/... examples would need root or sudo)

Comment: If you don't have a shell, what's going to run your command? I notice you've tagged the question with "scripting". Are you referring to some other scripting language than a shell scripting language (Perl? Python?). Please clarify the question.

Comment: `mailx`, `sed` *(the gnu variety can `e`xecute an arbitray shell command, even)*, `ed`, `ex`, `vi`, `xargs`, `csplit` *(some few versions)*, `luit` *(commonly packaged with `xterm`, so very often available)*, `dc` *(if your system can process a `system()` you can get a shell with `!`)*... a lot of these depend on a tty by basic  standard... even `pax` or `tar` can pull off what you ask with the right amount of crazy... anyway, can you not specify an output file with `curl`?

Comment: @mikeserv You're back! I have been assuming this all means "non-interactive, spawned from execve or similar", but it could be more explicit.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - yeah. some cop beat me up and stole my two-factor authed cell phone mar 2017 for crossing the street. i begged the googlebots for recognition for almost a year to get mikeserv@gmail.com back - i had it since early beta, and i never remember more than a couple total passwords. so i can sign in again because i somehow answered the g.co/recovery questions differently the umpteenth time. anyway, care to out me up, kiwi, if i flee the states? i dont have to live like a refugee...

Comment: Yes, using execvp()  or a similar mechanism is what I meant.  Also there are times when you do have a shell, but using |>< characters is awkward for some reason (bad escaping that mangles them, for instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know of any other non-empty file on the system, then with [POSIX `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

```
sed -e 's/.*/hello world/' -e 'wtarget' -e q otherfile
```

With GNU `sed` and just your own non-empty file, you can use:

```
sed -i.bak -e '$ihello world' -e 'd' foo
```

With BSD `sed`, this would work instead:

```
sed -i.bak -e '$i\
hello world' -e d foo
```

If you're not using a shell then presumably the linebreak isn't an issue.

---

[With `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_12), if the target file exists:

```
ex -c '0,$d' -c 's/^/hello world/' -c 'x' foo
```

This just deletes everything in the file, replaces the first line with "hello world", then writes and quits. You could do the same thing with `vi` in place of `ex`. Implementations are not required to support multiple `-c` options, but they generally do. For many `ex` implementations the requirement that the file already exist is not enforced.

---

Also [with `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
awk -v FN=foo -v STR="hello world" 'BEGIN{printf(STR) > FN }'
```

will write "hello world" to file "foo".

---

If there are existing files containing the bytes you want at known locations, you can assemble a file byte by byte over multiple commands with `dd` (in this case, `alphabet` contains the alphabet, but it could be a mix of input files):

```
dd if=alphabet bs=1 skip=7 count=1 of=test
dd if=alphabet bs=1 skip=4 count=1 seek=1 of=test
dd if=alphabet bs=1 skip=11 count=1 seek=2 of=test
dd if=alphabet bs=1 skip=11 count=1 seek=3 of=test
dd if=alphabet bs=1 skip=14 count=1 seek=4 of=test
cat test
hello
```

From there, just regular `cp` will work, or you might have been able to put it in-place to start with.

---

Less commonly, [the `mispipe` command from moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) allows constructing a shell-free pipe:

```
mispipe "echo 1" "tee wtarget"
```

is equivalent to `echo 1 | tee wtarget`, but returning the exit code of `echo`. This uses [the `system()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) internally, which doesn't *strictly* require a shell to exist.

---

Finally, `perl` is a common command and will let you write arbitrary programs to do whatever you want on the command line, as will `python` or any other common scripting language. Similarly, if a shell just isn't "running", but it does exist, `sh -c 'echo 1 > target'` will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Hello" > "/tmp/file"}'
```

When an `awk` program consists of only a `BEGIN` statement, it just interprets that statement and doesn't process any input.

You can even parameterise this

```
awk -v text="World" -v file="/tmp/main" 'BEGIN {print text > file}'
```

Though with that syntax, you'd need to escape backslash characters. Using `ARGV` doesn't have the problem:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print ARGV[1] > ARGV[2]}' World /tmp/main
```

Comment: They both work, but the second requires GNU awk - it doesn't work with BSD awk

Comment: @user1908704, that syntax is standard and comes from nawk. However, in the early versions, you needed `-v` and the assignment to be separate arguments (`-v var=value`, not `-vvar=value`), I've added the extra space.

Comment: @Kusalananda, can you please clarify? Though those are shell command lines, you don't need a shell to execute that `awk` command, you just need to call `awk`, with `["awk", "BEGIN {print ARGV[1] > ARGV[2]}", "World", "/tmp/main"]` as arguments  (using whatever syntax the non-shell context supports)